# How to delete rows older than some year?

Tags: mysql

I want delete rows from my database which is older than 4 year.this is my query.Is tat correect?Here "$year" is the year from my database table.

```
"DELETE FROM undergraudate WHERE YEAR(GETDATE())-'$year'>4"
```

Comment: What do you mean `$year` is the year from your database table.  It looks like a variable to me.  In addition, MySQL does not support `GETDATE()`.  You need to fix your question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and correctly tag the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your query won't work if today's date is 09th Jan 2016 and your date in table is 10th Nov 2012. So better you could do something like:

```
DELETE FROM undergraudate 
WHERE year > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1461 DAY))
```

Comment: here "year" is what?

Comment: I think `year` is the name of field in your database. This query is good because of you can create index on that field and it will work. In query from second answer it wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's looks fine but most probably you have datetime or date field in your database and so do like below. Again, `GETDATE()` is a SQL Server function. I think you meant `CURDATE()` or `NOW()`

```
DELETE FROM undergraudate 
WHERE YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(your-date-field) > 4
```